# The HERE toll cost and distance API is giving me this today. Am i doing something wrong?

Tags: here-api

The URL below was working for me yesterday. however this is the response I am getting today.
Here is my url:

`https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id={{API_ID}}&app_code={{API_CODE}}&currency=USD&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=4&trailerNumberAxles=2&emissionType=5&height=144in&trailerHeight=144in&vehicleWeight=12.0t&limitedWeight=20000lbs&commercial=1&waypoint0=38.8860434,-76.999525&waypoint1=39.3794196,-76.4599043`

here is my response:

`{"faultCode":"some_uuid","responseCode": "403","message":"Feature level access has been denied"}`

Is there something wrong in my request? ( NOTE: I am using a free trial, this API worked for me yesterday, all other APIs like normal routing and geocode retrieval are still working. )

Comment: Maybe your trial verison is expired

Comment: day 3 of my trial

Answer (score 1):

Although an old thread, answering here if anyone else runs into the issue. With the Freemium plans make sure to use the Production url for the API (without the cit in the url).

Comment: I didn't see this answer in a while. Thanks for the answer, Keeping this in mind for the future